# Hive Partitioned Table - trying to load data from one table to a partitioned table in my Hive and getting [Error 10044]*

Tags: hive, hiveql, parquet, hadoop2, hive-partitions

So I have a table with 20 columns and i created another partitioned table - using 2 partition values, now when i try to load data from my table with 20 columns into the other partitioned tables i get error saying my partitioned table has more columns than the table i am inserting data from

my create table statement:

```
  create table flight_data_parquet(
  YEAR INT,
  FL_DATE STRING,
  UNIQUE_CARRIER STRING,
  AIRLINE_ID INT,
  CARRIER STRING,
  TAIL_NUM STRING,
  FL_NUM INT,
  ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID INT,
  ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID INT,
  ORIGIN STRING,
  DEST_AIRPORT_ID INT,
  DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID INT,
  DEST STRING,
  DEP_DELAY FLOAT,
  ARR_DELAY FLOAT,
  CANCELLED TINYINT,
  DIVERTED TINYINT,
  DISTANCE INT)
partitioned by (Month INT, DAY_OF_MONTH INT)stored AS PARQUET;
```

-**insert statement**:

```
insert into table flight_data_parquet partition(month=1, day_of_month) 
select  YEAR,FL_DATE,
  UNIQUE_CARRIER,
  AIRLINE_ID,
  CARRIER,
  TAIL_NUM,
  FL_NUM,
  ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,
  ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,
  ORIGIN,
  DEST_AIRPORT_ID,
  DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,
  DEST,
  DEP_DELAY,
  ARR_DELAY,
  CANCELLED,
  DIVERTED,
  DISTANCE, month, day_of_month
from flight_data_v2 where month=1;
```

the error i get is -

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:18 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different 'day_of_month': Table insclause-0 has 19 columns, but query has 20 columns.
hive (flights)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`month=1` in the partition specification partition(**month=1**, day_of_month) - is a static partition and value is already specified , remove `month` from the select query. Only `day_of_month` (dynamic partition) should be in the select:

```
insert into table flight_data_parquet partition(month=1, day_of_month)  -- Month=1 is a static partition 
select  YEAR,FL_DATE,
  UNIQUE_CARRIER,
  AIRLINE_ID,
  CARRIER,
  TAIL_NUM,
  FL_NUM,
  ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,
  ORIGIN_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,
  ORIGIN,
  DEST_AIRPORT_ID,
  DEST_AIRPORT_SEQ_ID,
  DEST,
  DEP_DELAY,
  ARR_DELAY,
  CANCELLED,
  DIVERTED,
  DISTANCE, day_of_month
from flight_data_v2 where month=1;
```